# Android AssetPackManager registerListener SecurityException

Tags: android, android-assetpacks

To get a large amount of image into my app I use AssetPackManager, and that works well, up to Android 14, where the following error is produced:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException 
app.company.appname: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts.
```

Looking around for solutions, both in code and on the internet, I could not find anything. The log points to the next code:

```
assetPackManager?.let {
    it.fetch(Collections.singletonList(assetPackName))
    it.registerListener(mAssetPackStateUpdateListener)
}
```

And that uses:

```
var mAssetPackStateUpdateListener = AssetPackStateUpdateListener { state ->
    handleUpdate(state)
}
```

Checked Google Play Asset Delivery library: `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'`

But I cannot find where to set RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED.

What I am going to dig into is where the OS UI shows the download. I have no receivers on that, but the OS does show something is going on.

Has anyone experience with this error in combination with Asset Packs?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the Google Play Asset Delivery library?

Comment: Using: implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

Answer (score 1):

[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) put me on the right track.

[Android AssetPack](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java) have been changed somewhere in the last few years. `com.google.android.play:core:` **is deprecated**!

Use the following (or newer, check [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java))

```
// For Java:
implementation "com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.1.0"
// For Kotlin use asset-delivery-ktx
implementation "com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.1.0"
```

So, I was using an old library and testing, with hundreds op people, did not pick this up...

*Will come back to see if this fixes things in the wild.

Comment: I didn't catch this either, thanks for the visibility!